# Run yii project using hhvm

Tags: php, yii, hhvm

How can I start Yii2 project using HHVM?

Run

```
hhvm yii serve
```

but I got the following error:

```
Server started on http://localhost:8080/
Document root is "/home/hgminh95/Documents/pk-homepage-server/web"
Quit the server with CTRL-C or COMMAND-C.
Error in command line: unrecognised option '-S'
Usage:

   /usr/bin/hhvm [-m <mode>] [<options>] [<arg1>] [<arg2>] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

HHVM is linux only. It doesn't have anything for Windows and for MacOS it works in limited mode without JIT compiler.

Check this 
https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/performance-hhvm/

```
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 0x5a16e7281be7a449
echo deb http://dl.hhvm.com/debian wheezy main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/hhvm.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install hhvm
```

Comment: I am currently using Ubuntu

Comment: @MinhHoàng clearly already has HHVM installed, and "HHVM is Linux only" is false anyway: http://hhvm.com/blog/10043/experimental-mac-os-x-support

Comment: Read this then down vote..  @Josh Watzman.. 
 https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/performance-hhvm/